# Is canva website used Backbone js..?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, backbone.js

I am going to do a web app which is relatively same as [canva](https://www.canva.com/). I am very eager to know which js framework they used.

### My question:

They used Backbone js..?

- If yes, why they used for it..?
- If no, what js they used..?

I searched for the js framework they used in their [canva engineering site](https://engineering.canva.com/2015/10/01/tech-talks-august-2015/), but can't able to retrieve the details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are using php+backbone js.
I think php for their rest api's and backbone for DOMmanipulations

Comment: @ Siraj Abbas.. Can your share any link or reference to confirm that they used Backbone js..?

Comment: https://builtwith.com/canva.com   if helped mark as right answer

Comment: @ Siraj Abbas.. ok.. I am going to pick Angular JS as my web app js framework. Is it good..?

Comment: personaly i prefer angularjs1.It is awesome.i have done several projects using angulsr.Go ahead.

Comment: plz feel free to ask any queries in angular

Comment: @ Siraj Abbas.. ok.. sure...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128050/discussion-between-arunvalaven-and-siraj-abbas).